# What does 'eno' stand for in network device name 'eno16777736' on CentOS 7 or RHEL 7?

Tags: network-interface, centos7

For consistent network device naming, what does 'eno' stand for in network interface name 'eno16777736' on CentOS 7 or RHEL 7?

Answer (score 0):

This is Predictable Network Interface Device Names in action.

en is for Ethernet

o is for on-board

The number is a firmware/BIOS provided index.

More details in the source of udev-builtin-net_id.c

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the option:

real machine:

1. Ensure you have **net.ifnames=1 biosdevname=1** in **grub.cfg** file.
2. Change **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-enX** to **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-ethX**
3. Ensure that the option **DEVICE=ethX** in file **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-ethX** (the option is very importance)

Vmware machine:

1. You need to add **net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0** in **grub.cfg** file.
2. Change **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-enX** to **/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-ethX**

After all, reboot the machine.

In my case, I do not add any rules or something like this. Hope the solution will help you